# Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I imported the project from unity to Android Studio, I can run it on the device and everything works fine, but when I try to connect Firebase to the project, I get this error immediately after connecting.

I found similar problems and mostly they advise adding

These two lines, but it doesn't help me.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I also added the json file from Firebase to the project.

```
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimatorRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyThread found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ArrayRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AttrRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BinderThread found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BoolRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.CallSuper found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.CheckResult found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ChecksSdkIntAtLeast found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorInt found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorLong found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ContentView found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.DimenRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
    Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Dimension found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
   ...
    Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

My build.gradle(project)

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            // If you are changing the Android Gradle Plugin version, make sure it is compatible with the Gradle version preinstalled with Unity
            // See which Gradle version is preinstalled with Unity here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html
            // See official Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin compatibility table here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
            // To specify a custom Gradle version in Unity, go do "Preferences > External Tools", uncheck "Gradle Installed with Unity (recommended)" and specify a path to a custom Gradle version
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'

        }
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle(module launcher)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':unityLibrary')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.2.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        applicationId 'com.MyCompany.test'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', '.bundle', '.unityexp'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}
```

Мой build.gradle (module libary)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'googlemobileads-unity', ext:'aar')
    implementation project('GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', '.bundle', '.unityexp'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }
}
```

and gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.enableR8=false
unityStreamingAssets=.json
unityTemplateVersion=3
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: As it is clearly mentioned you have duplicate files.